# Add an element to the list after x of N rounds

Tags: python, list, insert, addition

Let's say I have the following list in python:

```
probs = [0.1, 0.4, 0.9]
```

the number of experiments is 20 (N_episodes) and after x experiments, e.g. 10, I want to add an element to the list.

I already came up with a for loop:

```
for i in range(N_episodes):
        new_bandit = np.random.random()
        new_bandit_probs = probs.append(new_bandit)
```

but this gives me endless new elements, I just want one new element. Can someone help me out?

Answer (score 1):

You can probably use this:

```
x = 10 # The number of experiments after which you need to add number.
for i in range(N_episodes):
    if i == x:
        new_bandit = np.random.random()
        new_bandit_probs = probs.append(new_bandit)
```